# Problem with plotting bar plot using plotly

Tags: pandas, plotly, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to plot bar plot with average target per city, however it results in another plot
Here is the code:

```
temp = df.groupby('city').mean()
temp = temp.sort_values('target')

bar_data = go.Bar(x=temp['target'], y=temp.target.index , orientation='h',opacity=0.6)

data = bar_data
layout = go.Layout(title='Price by City', xaxis={'title':'Price'}, yaxis={'title':'City'}, height=800)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please do share a sample of your data. It is otherwise hard to help you. You can simply post the output of ```df.head(50).to_dict()``` in you question. Remember to post that within two instances of ```

Comment: Is temp['target'] in numeric format?